# LED dimming - eliminate EMI

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, amperage

Looking for some advice.
I have a subsea light that operates at about 10-14v, but accepts up to 32vdc input(0-1.7A).

My power supply is 24vdc 10A. Cable length 100 meter +.  At max the lights draw 11 watt. The issue is that I have analog audio through the same cable so EMI is an issue, and PWM creates too much interference.

Light needs to be controlled through a potentiometer. I was thinking about buying https://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=459174 and swapping out the multi turn trimpot with a knob operated pot http://www.robotpark.com/10K-Potentiometer . The pot however needs to be placed about 2 meters away, or possibly 20 cm if I make some rebuild, and could pick up interference? Maybe using a twisted shielded pair could help?

The pot would have a lot less travel, but may be OK for light dimming.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: "PWM creates too much interference." but you want to use a buck converter. Buck converters _USE_ PWM. They do so, (almost always) at frequencies above audio. That may or may not cause you problems, but if a buck converter at some high frequency, say 250kHz does not give you trouble, then PWM is not your problem.  However, your idea to use a buck converter is a good one because the buck converter is already fabricated, no need to start from scratch, and because it already has a smoothing capacitor in it, which reduces sharp edges and ripple.

Comment: What PWM are you referring to? Are you using a PWM controller? If so, describe it and your setup and maybe you will get some suggestions.

Comment: Check your CMRR on EMI and suppress CM noise, then update question with results

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy You're right of course. I'm very much learning at this point. I just found the following page [link](https://www.electroschematics.com/dimmer-box/)which confirms that my PWM dimmer is at a frequency within audio (about 600Hz) I actually already tried piggybacking a capacitor to change the frequency, but might not have got the frequency right. The Velleman converter is at 150kHz, I will test and check if interference persists. 

My current dimmer comes in a couple of different configurations ; 
[link](https://ibb.co/B6BFzKg)
[link](https://ibb.co/xjQdqLp)

Comment: EMI wise it's never a good idea to put square waves on cables. You can try to dull the edges (reduce harmonics) or dim the LED's using current control rather then PWM.

Comment: I had extra components so I set up a bench test. 
The original setup includes dc/dc converter, video, light, audio and a 4-20ma sensor.
My bench differs in that I use a 12v DC wall adapter and I haven't hooked up the 4-20 ma components. 
Bench test with Velleman LM2596S module had no noise/EMI. 
My original 12-24v 8a pwm dimmer which had noise previously, no noise this time. 
Could it be the 4-20ma sensor/loop? I know they handle EMI quite well, but not sure to what degree they can cause interference on analog audio. 
Otherwise my next step will be looking for faulty components I guess.

Comment: DC/DC 24v converter [link](https://products.pulspower.com/ca/cd5-243.html)
Velleman module [link](https://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=435566)
12-24v 8a pwm dimmer [link](https://www.diffusioneshop.com/en/led-dimmer-12-24v-8a-with-rotary-potentiometer)